# Unity Master Server Vs Simple Client Server

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, client-server, wifi, unityscript

I have written two programs and i want both of these to run on my android device which are on the same network but one which is simple client server program it will run on both device and connection will be made...But Unity Master Server will not run fine and not able to connect two android wifi device which are on the same network and this program will run fine on localhost.
Here is simple client server code..This code run fine

```
var object:Transform;
 static var Isconnected:boolean=false;
//172.16.11.4
function Start()
{
Application.runInBackground = true;
Debug.Log("run in back groud");
}
function Update()
{
if(Isconnected)
  var temp:Transform;
  temp=Instantiate(object,transform.position, transform.rotation);
}
function OnGUI()
{
if(Network.peerType==NetworkPeerType.Disconnected)
{
  if(GUILayout.Button(" Initlized server"))
  {
   var useNat = !Network.HavePublicAddress();
   Network.InitializeServer(32,25001,useNat);
   Debug.Log("Server has been Initlized");
  }
 } 
  if(GUILayout.Button("connect to server"))
  {
    Network.Connect("172.16.11.4",25001);
  }
}
function OnConnectedToServer() {
    Debug.Log("Connected to server");
    Isconnected=true;
    // Send local player name to server ...
}
```

But this code will not run on wifi...WHile this code run on localhost if we give the ip 127.0.0.1

```
#pragma strict
private var rotAngle : float = 0;
private var pivotPoint : Vector2;
var Gamename:String="MyGame";
var refreshing:boolean=false;
private var hostdata:HostData[];

function Start () {

}

function Update () {
var farword=Input.GetKey("up");
if(farword==true)
{
//animation.Play("ArmatureAction");

}
transform.Translate(0,0,Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
transform.Rotate(0,Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),0);
if(refreshing)
{
if(MasterServer.PollHostList().Length>0)
{
refreshing=false;
hostdata=MasterServer.PollHostList();
Debug.Log(MasterServer.PollHostList().Length);

}
}



}
function startServer()
{
Network.InitializeServer(32,25001,!Network.HavePublicAddress);
MasterServer.RegisterHost(Gamename,"THis is tutorial","THis is tutorial game");
}
function OnServerInitialized()
{
Debug.Log("Sever is initlized");
}
function OnMasterServerEvent(mgs:MasterServerEvent)
{
if(mgs==MasterServerEvent.RegistrationSucceeded)
{
Debug.Log("Register server");
}



}
function refreshHostList(){
MasterServer.RequestHostList(Gamename);
  refreshing=true;

}







function OnGUI()
{
if((!Network.isClient && !Network.isServer))
{
if(GUI.Button(Rect(100,100,100,100),"Start Sever"))
{
Debug.Log("Start Server");
startServer();
}
if(GUI.Button(Rect(100,220,100,100),"Refresg Hosts"))
{
Debug.Log("Refresh HOsts");
refreshHostList();
}

if(hostdata)
{
for(var i:int=0;i<hostdata.length;i++)
{
 if(GUI.Button(Rect(230,100,100,100),hostdata[i].gameName))
 {
 Network.Connect("172.16.11.4",25001);
 }
}
}
}
if(GUI.Button(Rect(300,300,100,100),"back"))
{
transform.Translate(9,0,0);
}
if(GUI.Button(Rect(300,400,100,100),"farword"))
{
transform.Translate(-9,0,0);
}

}
```

Any help

Answer (score 0):

I think in second code

```
if(hostdata) 
{ 
for(var i:int=0;i<hostdata.length;i++) 
{ 
  if(GUI.Button(Rect(230,100,100,100),hostdata[i].gameName)) 
  { 
  Network.Connect("172.16.11.4",25001); 
  } 
}
```

need to change

```
if(hostdata) 
{ 
for(var i:int=0;i<hostdata.length;i++) 
{ 
  if(GUI.Button(Rect(230,100,100,100),hostdata[i].gameName)) 
  { 
   Network.Connect(hostdata[i]); //Or Network.Connect( hostdata[i].ip[ 0 ], hostdata[i].port ); 
  } 
}
```

And also your buttons will overlay themselves. (if more than 1 server initialized and found). You need to create Rect with dynamic start height value. Like:

```
if(hostdata) 
{ 

 var y = 100;  // or other start y position like 0
 for(var i:int=0;i<hostdata.length;i++) 
 { 

  if(GUI.Button(Rect(230,y,100,100),hostdata[i].gameName)) 
  { 
   Network.Connect(hostdata[i]); //Or Network.Connect( hostdata[i].ip[ 0 ], hostdata[i].port ); 
  } 
  y+=100+ 5 //Some padding.
}
```

if any problems occurs like can not connect the server keep in mind NAT punchthrough generally cause problems.